# ErrorException Array to string conversion Laravel - Importing JSON to MySQL

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, string

I try to import JSON formatted file into MySQL database. I put this code in the web.php:

```
Route::get('/pages', function(){
    $json = file_get_contents(storage_path('posts_and_comments.json'));
    $objs = json_decode($json,true);
    foreach ($objs as $obj)  {
        foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
            $insertArr[Str::slug($key,'_')] = $value;
        }
        DB::table('my_likes')->insert($insertArr);
    }
    dd("Finished adding data in examples table");
});
```

It gave me a ErrorException Array to string conversion Laravel. How can I solve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try encoding array as a json object than insert it to db ?

```
foreach ($objs as $obj)  {
    foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
        $insertArr[Str::slug($key,'_')] = json_encode($value);
    }
    DB::table('my_likes')->insert($insertArr);
}
```

Comment: It gave me error: TypeError
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array, string given, called in..\routes\web.php on line 39  (it's the line of your given code)

Comment: Elements of $insertArr might not be string values . Can you print the content of $insertArr & edit your question